Python13 was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings>Manage App Execution Aliases
i am running python -m venv venv
then i encountered the above error
after i turned off python by going here Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.
I started encountering this error
python : The term 'python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

python -m venv venv

  + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (python:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException




I tried re-installing all extensions and python version on my system
but of no use, then finally what I did helped me
Sounds like there is an issue with the interpreter.
1> Open the Command Palette in Visual Studio Code by pressing Ctrl + Shift + P
2> Type "Python: Select Interpreter" and select it.
3> Choose the conda environment that you want to use from the list of available interpreters.
4> After selecting the interpreter, close and reopen VSC (for changes to take effect).
Once you have the correct interpreter, you should be able to run the script in the terminal.
And it works!
